# Why are the network connections in the Network System Preference panel mislabeled?

Tags: network, wifi, system-settings, ethernet

Here is a screenshot of a problem I am having. The wireless connection is mis-labled as Ethernet and my wired connection is mis-labeled as Wi-Fi.

[image: screenshot]

`/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist` appears to have the correct labels for the correct interfaces.

Why might these interfaces be mislabeled? Could this cause problems? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do all users on your Mac have this problem? If you create a new user, does the problem persist?

Comment: @BartArondson - This is a single user system. I can create a new user and see.

Comment: I don't think you have to create a new user. If you just follow @lukiffer's advice you will solve the problem. Don't forget to mark his answer as correct!

Answer (score 2):

We had this problem when we provisioned an image taken from another device. It won't hurt anything, but if it bothers you, you can rename it from the UI.

Click the gear drop-down at the bottom of the list, then select "Rename Service"